# Right-moving Turing Machines

Tags: computer-science

The idea of a read-only right-moving Turing Machine already exists [1].
Is there a relaxed version of this where an input-reading head only moves 
right to read inputs as needed? There may be other heads doing the computation
on work tapes; the movement of these heads is unrestricted.

Of course the right-moving head could simply copy the contents to another unrestricted TM tape and start that; I'm trying to study TM configurations where the TM works as much as possible before requesting another input character.

I'm assuming this machine is Turing complete; correct me if I'm wrong.

References with your answer would be helpful. Thanks

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-only_right_moving_Turing_Machines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could copy the input to a work tape and go on from there.